# Save a multilingual site as template

Tags: site-template, custom-list, multilingual

I created a site and set the language settings to multiple languages, so users can switch between different languages for the MUI.

But I have also custom columns in a list. So, i translated the titles of the custom columns by switching through the languages and changed each column title.

So, that works fine.

But i want to export this site as a template, so it can be re-used. But if i have 5 different languages in my "original" site, i have only one language in my site created with the site template. And so, i also loose all information about my translated custom site column titles.

Is there a solution to export all this information in a site template.

And if not, is there a solution to manage translatable custom site columns (without variations).

Thanks.

Comment: I think when you export a site template, it asks you if you want to include everything (can't remmeber what comes in everything) but yeah try it.

Comment: I just tried it but it is the same result

Comment: Having the same issue now. I need to have all the alternative languages i activated on the site i used to create my template to stay activated when i create a new Site from the template.

Comment: Have you tried importing it with the API you can define the target language of the template. As long as your template is 1033 it should be fine *Theory*

Answer (score 1):

I don't think this can be done. If you want those site columns to be reused on other sites, having the correct translations, you're better of using a custom solution with a site feature anyway.

Suppose you've got your source site and you want to add a new column including translations. Or suppose you've reused you're columns on three sites, and then you find out for one column s single translation is wrong. That's all stuff you don't want to deal with.

So in my opinion there's to options: 
1. Build a solution for the site columns.
2. Use the medata content type hub to publish your site columns onto different sites, that should work multilingual as well.